Maplibre render POI on self-hosted 3D OSM
I am trying to render POI on an OSM pbf extract, shown using maplibre. What I have tried so far hasn't worked. There is a live demo here.
That demo doesn't have the latest PBF from GeoFabrik as that is still downloading, though I tested the below on a smaller OSM extract. The process I followed to get to this point is here.
I can see the POI in the OSM extract:
 <node id="12065021076" visible="true" version="3" changeset="154203884" timestamp="2024-07-21T05:43:05Z" user="TRH Team" uid="14519448" lat="51.8328083" lon="-0.7006749">
  <tag k="destroyed" v="building"/>
  <tag k="destroyed:date" v="1941-01-30"/>
  <tag k="ele" v="8"/>
  <tag k="historic" v="building"/>
  <tag k="image" v="https://www.tringruralhistory.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2023/01/KJCHNk0s.jpeg"/>
  <tag k="inscription" v="Long Marston School"/>
  <tag k="source" v="local knowledge;https://www.tringruralhistory.co.uk/articles/a-day-of-tragedy-the-childrens-view/"/>
  <tag k="website" v="https://www.tringruralhistory.co.uk/articles/a-day-of-tragedy-the-childrens-view/"/>
 </node>

And I added style information to style.json
    map.addLayer({
      "id": "historic-3d",
      "type": "symbol",
      "source": "openmaptiles",
      "source-layer": "poi",
      "layout": {
        "text-field": "{name:latin}",
        "text-font": ["Klokantech Noto Sans Regular"],
        "text-max-width": 10,
        "text-size": {"stops": [[3, 12], [8, 16]]}
      },
      "paint": {
        "text-color": "hsl(0, 0%, 0%)",
        "text-halo-blur": 0,
        "text-halo-color": "hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.75)",
        "text-halo-width": 2
      }
    });

